# Как вывести данные с многостраничного api? Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Имею многостраничный api, необходимо вывести данные со всех страниц сразу, а не только с одной.
Вот на этом моменте и случается мой "камень преткновения".
Код на данный момент выглядит вот так (service.ts):

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Planet, pagesApi } from './intfs';
import { Observable, tap } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class PlService {

  url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getPlanets(): Observable<Planet[]> {
    return this.http.get<Planet[]>(this.url)
        .pipe(map((data: any) => {
          return data['results'];
        }))
  }
}
```

Как его доработать, чтобы можно было вывести данные со всех страниц?
За помощь заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый, наверное, простой и быстрый способ получить массив с объектами страниц - это использовать `zip`.

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, zip } from 'rxjs';
import _ from 'lodash'; // lodash просто для удобства

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any',
})
export class PlService {
  readonly URL_PLANETS = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  // Если нужны определенные страницы от 1 до 10 и т.д
  getAllPlanets(): Observable<any[]> { // интерфейс Planet заменил на any, чтобы протестировать, т.к Planet вы не показали
    return zip(
      ..._.range(1, 11).map((page) =>
        this._http.get(this.URL_PLANETS + page + '/')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

- Подробнее про `zip` читайте в [документации RxJs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip)
- про `_.range()` можно прочтиать [тут](https://lodash.com/docs/#range)

Comment: Planet это: export interface Planet {
  name: string;
  rotation_period: string;
  orbital_period: string;
  diameter: string; и так далее Критично что-то меняет или ваше решение подходит?

Comment: @bububi_21 это не важно. Замените ``any[]`` на ``Planet[]`` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, разберусь с тем что вы предложили. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Ваш код выдает ошибку в синтаксисе, а я понять не могу почему, вот в это месте `..._.range(1, 11).map`  Ошибка TS2304, а range определяется как css элемент

Comment: @bububi_21, у вас скорее всего не установлен ``lodash``.  Я сделал это просто для удобства, не обязятельно использовать ``range()``. Если заменить ``..._.range(1, 11).map`` на  `...[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map`, в семантике ничего не изменится. Либо установите его с помощью команды ``npm i --save lodash``.